# A noun to be used for something normalized

Tags: word-choice, nouns, programming

I'm looking for a noun that can be used to describe some object that was *normalized*.

The situation is this - I have an *original* object (which I also refer to as *original*, as a noun), and I normalize it - so now I have *normalized* object, but I'd prefer to refer to the normalized object by noun too.

Some possible words that came to my mind were *standard*, *regular*, or even *normal* - but I think saying *normal* object would not explain the fact that the object went through a normalization process in enough detail.

Does English has any word that could refer to this? This is to be used during programming, so any term not common in general English but common in programming would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: It does not sound like you are looking for a noun. Your reference to *standard*, *regular*, and *normal* indicates you are looking for an adjective. The adjective you want is right in front of you: *normalized*; it is a *normalized* object/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to come up with a new term and have a sense of humor, then

**vendible**

would be a good candidate. As in, "Here's the *vendible*. May I keep the *original*, though?

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vendible

Answer (score 0):

***[certified](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/certified)*** might work for you.

A FIFA certified ball  (or NFL certified helme) .  That implies that norms were derived in a process and that the given object is guaranteed to meet the norms. The word is used in other ways to mean "endorsed" that don't necessarily imply norms but gurantees ... but very frequently it is used as an attestment to meeting norms.

> **cer·ti·fy**  (sûr′tə-fī′)
>
> v. cer·ti·fied, cer·ti·fy·ing, cer·ti·fies
>   v.tr.
>
> 1. a. To confirm formally as true, accurate, or genuine:
>
> *The police certified that a suspect had been arrested.*
>
> b. **To guarantee as meeting a standard:**
>
> ***butter that was certified Grade A.***